# API to get user anniversary from Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I noticed that the Graph API (e.g. GET https://graph.facebook.com/UID) returns `relationship_status` and `significant_other`, but does not return an anniversary date for the relationship even if one is present.

Is it possible to see this via the Graph (or even REST) API?

EDIT: There is no API for the same. Instead you could simply screen scrape the user's profile page where anniversary is listed on the bottom. Much easier but its a violation of Facebook's term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to get this right now, hope for an update of the API.

The unofficial only ways would be screen scraping or parsing all posts on the users wall but both ways are not every efficient and screen scraping is not even allowed by the terms of Facebook.

Comment: Instead of wall, I could simply screen scrape the user's profile page where anniversary is listed on the bottom. Much easier but as you mentioned, its a violation of facebook's term. So I guess i will have to add a way to prompt the user to ask his friends to fill in their details.

Comment: Is there still no official way to fetch Anniversary of an FB user ?

Answer (score 1):

There don't seems to be any way to access this information through any Facebook API.

As you told in your question, the only informations available are relationship_status and significant_other (with correct permissions).

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way to do this. However, if you are still intent on doing this, you could parse everything on the user's wall, and see when they updated their relationship status to "In a relationship" or married or whatever they do now. This would probably be a better approach than looking for "happy anniversary".

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, I have not found this data to be available through the API.
Crazy workaround :):

You could parse all the comments your user has posted on the wall of his significant-other.
If a post contains "(happy)? anniversary" - that's your date!