# Get relationship anniversary using Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to get the user's **relationship anniversary**, like wedding anniversary, using Facebook Graph API 2.3?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053828/api-to-get-user-anniversary-from-facebook

Comment: The link provided by @kmandov is a few years old. Has anything changed since then?

Comment: @Matt I didn't find any progress...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life event cannot be accessed by graph api. Here is a doc for it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/life-event, but you cannot get authority to fetch any event for user.